# String or binary data would be truncated. -- even though length shorter than field length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to prefix a string field on a table by using the UPDATE command. For some reason I'm getting the

> String or binary data would be truncated.

exception, even though the length of my data would easily fit in the field.

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition and SSMS 2008 R2.

<strike>Template: Learner is a nvarchar(60)</strike>

**Template: Learner is a nvarchar(30) using 60 bytes as shown in sp_help**

```sql
select LEN('Aaaaaaaa' + LEFT(learner, 52)) myLen from Template order by myLen desc
>>> max len = 31

update Template set learner = 'Aaaaaaaa' + LEFT(learner, 52)
>>> String or binary data would be truncated.

update Template set learner = 'Aaaaaaaa' + LEFT(learner, 52)
>>> String or binary data would be truncated.

update Template set learner = CAST('Aaaaaaaa' + LEFT(learner, 52) AS NVARCHAR(60))
>>> String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Whereas the following works:

```
SELECT CAST('Aaaaaaaa' + LEFT(learner, 52) AS NVARCHAR(60)) FROM Template
```

Comment: Any triggers on the table?

Comment: Nope, but that's a great tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.

Looks like I was fooled by the length value on **sp_help** and **sp_columns**. As it's a NVARCHAR column the length means the length in bytes and not the number of characters. This is because NVARCHAR = Unicode (UTF-16) => 2 Bytes per character.

Looking at the **CREATE** script revealed the truth. Also the PRECISION field on sp_columns shows the number of characters too.

Answer (score 7):

You can try to ignore this message by

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
update ...
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

Comment: Ignoring a message without understanding why it happened is always a very bad idea.

Comment: You right, but sometimes you just need to move on ignoring minor warnings.

Comment: I agree, but this one indicates data loss and is therefore not "minor". So again: First understand - then decide.

Comment: Never say always. Thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was having another log table (for audit trail), filled by a trigger on the main table, where the column size also had to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason could be having a nonsensical column CONSTRAINT with a Default Value that is longer than the max value.

Example:

[image: Default Value longer than max value]

The error would occur when inserting without specifying this column in the insert statement.